# What are the drawbacks of using Data Binding in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding

I have recently transitioned from using `findViewById` to using `view binding`. This was a relatively easy change. Using `view binding` as opposed to `findViewById` shorted my code and made it more readable. Now, as I progress to more advanced modules in the [Android Basics in Kotlin Course](https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course), I am increasingly in contact with `data binding`. This, however, has been a difficult shift and I have some concerns.

I would like to cite the following snippets of data binding from the "[Shared ViewModel Across Fragments](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-kotlin-unit-3-pathway-4%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#7)" Codelab:

**Reference the View Model**

```
<layout ...>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.cupcake.model.OrderViewModel" />
    </data>

    <ScrollView ...>

    ...
```

**Binding data to View**

```
<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/option1"
   ...
   android:checked="@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[1])}"
   android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[1])}"
   android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[1]}"
   ... />

<RadioButton
   android:id="@+id/option2"
   ...
   android:checked="@{viewModel.date.equals(viewModel.dateOptions[2])}"
   android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.setDate(viewModel.dateOptions[2])}"
   android:text="@{viewModel.dateOptions[2]}"
   ... />
```

Using these snippets as references, what are some disadvantages of binding data (from code) directly to views in XML layouts? Does it possibly diminish the principle of *separation of concerns* by adding data logic to file responsible for controlling style and appearance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion these are some downsides:

- Less readable
- Harder to debug because you can't set breakpoints in xml
- More/harder to resolve merge conflicts if working with multiple devs on the same project
- Layouts aren't as reusable because you may not have the same viewmodel and data available
- Can't see the text in Android Studio preview (this can be alleviated by using tools:text)